# Mat-button-toggle loses group styling if not a direct child of mat-button-toggle-group

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have the Angular template code below, and I'm using some structural directives to display certain buttons on screen according to a value `aspectChoice` set elsewhere on the page.

What I want to do, is display all of the options of resolutionAssetMappings where the element's `other.aspectRatio` property matches the `aspectChoice` value. This is fine, it works properly.

The only issue is that since `mat-button-toggle` needs to be a direct child of `mat-button-toggle-group` in order to benefit from the styling applied to each button. Since the div element separates them, they aren't being styled properly.

However, Angular doesn't let you put more than one structural directive onto a single element. So having both the *ngFor and the *ngIf on the `mat-button-toggle` element is impossible. Meaning I need the div to separate them so I can iterate over the resAssetMappings array and THEN check whether or not the button element in question should be displayed or not.

```
<mat-button-toggle-group formControlName="resolutionChoice" class="button-group">
                <div *ngFor="let resolution of resolutionAssetMappings">
                  <mat-button-toggle *ngIf="resolution.other.aspectRatio === aspectChoice"
                                     class="option-button" value="{{resolution.name}}">
                    {{resolution.prettyName}}
                  </mat-button-toggle>
                </div>
              </mat-button-toggle-group>
```

Is there a way I can alter this so that I can have both the behaviour I want and the styling?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was to replace the `div` element with the `ng-container` element. The ng-container isn't rendered to the DOM but also allows you to apply both structural directives.